# GDB - proc info mapping vs /proc/pid/mapping

Tags: debugging, unix, memory, gdb, coredump

Using GDB, it is written that the command `info proc mappings` shows a list of mapped memory regions in the running process. Same as the the output of `/prod/pid/maps`.

- What is happening when running `info proc mappings` on a core dump file?
- The output is not the same. Which regions are saved in the core dump?
- Why it doesn't save all the mappings but only some of the mapped regions?